# Using Projecions to fetch a particular column from child table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, projection

I have two tables

```
Loan (id, amount, duration)

LoanStatus(id, status, loan_id)   // just an example, but it has lot more fields in this table
```

Loan.java

```
public class Loan{

    private int id;
    private int amount;
    private int duration;
    private LoanStatus loanStatus;

    // getter and setters

}
```

LoanStatus.java

```
public class LoanStatus{   // just an example, but it has many fields than what actually given

    private int id;
    private String status;
    private Loan loan;

    //getter and setters

}
```

Now I would like to get only `amount` , `duration` , `loanStatus.status` using Projections. I've used `createAlias()` to successfully fetch that particular column, but the problem occurs when setting it to a setter.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Loan.class,"loan");
    criteria.createAlias("loan.loanStatus", "loanStatus")
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("id"),"id")
            .add(Projections.property("amount"),"amount")
            .add(Projections.property("duration"),"duration")
            .add(Projections.property("loanStatus.status"), "loanStatus"))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Loan.class));
    return criteria.list();
```

I've an error which as follows.

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.site.dto.Loan.loanStatus (expected type = com.site.dto.LoanStatus)]; target = [com.site.dto.Loan@4083974a], property value = [Pending]
```

So I'm getting my expected column value "Pending", but the problem is when setting it to a setter. I've seen many question for projections, but most of them was based on Restrictions using Projections but not fetching a child's particular column using projections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own custom transformer. The following implementation might be exactly what you need

https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer . The usage example as written in their docs

```
class Person {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Car car;
  // getters and setters
}

class Car {
  private Long id;
  private String color;
  // getters and setters
}

List<Person> getPeople() {
  ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.id().as("id"))
    .add(Projections.property("name").as("name"))
    .add(Projections.property("c.id").as("car.id"))
    .add(Projections.property("c.color").as("car.color"));

  Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class)
    .createAlias("car", "c")
    .setProjection(projections)
    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(Person.class));

  return (List<Person>) criteria.list();
}

// each car of Person will be populated
```

Comment: But exactly in reverse, I've loanStatus as an object in loan class for one to one mapping and also for easy restrictions based on status. To be straight, I need only status field from loanStatus object, but it should be available as loanStatus object instead of just a string coz I've some further jaxb XML conversions

Comment: I've edited an answer, didn't notice that the Loan class was an Entity as well, I tought it was simple a data transfer object

Comment: Thanks.. I too thought about that. But I've many statuses present in loan status, so I don't think its a good practise to create transient field for each status. I'm just wondering is it possible to get a child's particular fields as child object instead of making a transient field in parent object.

Comment: For eg, if I call loan.getLoanStatus().getStatus(), it should return status. But if I call loan.getLoanStatus().getSomeOtherFields(), it should return null. This is my expected output. Like fetching only few columns in parent table using projections, I should also able to fetch only needed columns in child AS child object but not as a field in parent object

Comment: was about to suggest writting a custom transformer, and found an implementation online that you could most likely use as is

Comment: Just had a look at it and I think, that's the kind of exact solution I've been looking. Will implement that now. Thanks. btw, you could edit your answer to make that link as an exact answer for helping future visitors..

Comment: Just to inform you, I do get nested child object as child object by using AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer, but it's fetching all the fields of parent and child no matter what the only fields I've defined in Projections.

Comment: @Master Slave if i have list of car objects in peron class can still be used?